# What type of sensor (w/ bluetooth)?

Tags: sensor

I own a cafe very close to a university campus. As such I get lots of students coming in to buy drinks/food and study during the day. However, a lot of the time all of the available places will fill up and I feel as if this turns off students from coming in because they don't know for sure that they'll be able to get a spot. To fix this I wanted to create a type of system with sensors (that can be connected via bluetooth low energy preferably) in which I'll receive real time updates with how many chairs are occupied/open.

Currently I'm torn between three different approaches but since this is more of a side project I also want to minimize the cost as much as possible. I was thinking of either a proximity detector (easily placed on the side/back/under the chair), a force/load sensor (tougher to set up since it will need to be under a load bearing part of the chair), or a vibration sensor (will return 'occupied' if it hasn't sensed any chair vibrations for a certain period of time eg. 2 minutes).

What would you guys recommend here taking price into consideration?

Comment: shopping questions are off-topic. Temperature would be a decent method if your patrons are living and carbon-based.

Comment: Asking for a source for a part is known here as a shopping question and can get your question closed.  Besides that, the question is very broad, which is also grounds for closing.  I've not placed a vote to close, but others can and may do so.  At the very least, remove the request for a source for the sensors.

Comment: I expect you will have to build something that fits your needs.  A complete sensor that send a bluetooth message on a particular set of conditions (vibration free, 2 minutes) probably won't be any kind of off the shelf anything.

Comment: If you can get a camera in a position to cover the room, a machine vision system may give you a good number without having to deploy one sensor per chair (and keep them all charged!): http://blogs.wcode.org/2015/04/footfall-a-camera-based-people-counting-system-for-under-60/

Comment: +1 Hardly a shopping question. It amazes me what people think you can "just buy". Maybe I live in the wrong word. "Excuse me, I 'd like a cafe chair occupancy cots system please. MUST not involve ANY design". Yeah , right.  Cmon guys. !!!

Comment: @pjc50 good idea.....Also if you(I mean OP) want to use sensors then pir sensors might be a good idea... but might be costly option....

Comment: Re "Besides that, the question is very broad, which is also grounds for closing" Broad ???????????? Nicely specific real world system design question. How could it be narrowed usefully without missing the point?

Comment: I figure it for a shopping question for saying "what would you recommend and where can I get it for the cheapest price."  I didn't vote to close, because it also asks a lot of other stuff, and that one sentence could be removed to make it not a shopping question.

Comment: Broad, yes.  I've seen questions closed that were less broad than this one.  I personally like this question, and others like it.  They do have a tendency to get closed, though.  [Like this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/220932/different-ways-to-detect-seals/220943)

Comment: @JRE that seal detection question has lots of information relevant to this one, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chair vibrations has the potential to be hard.

A leg to floor sensor should be not too hard but you need to make it robust enough. A (gasp) microswitch and a slightly compressible pad on two legs would work. Seat surface deflection should be doable.
Light occlusion in seat area would usually work.
Piezo disc under chair leg(s) would do something. Robustness an issue.

Capacitive proximity is easy enough. Cost may be high for finished units. Doing it yourself with an IC designed for that or even a processor that has cap-sense software available could be low cost.

BLE is not the only way. An eg ESP2866 system that wakes the processor up occasionally (once a minute?) may suffice.

Ask more if desired ... .

Comment: TI MSP430 has a good capsense demo, so that could be quite cheap. Piezos under the chairleg would be destroyed as soon as someone drags a chair, but might work in some other part of the chair.

Comment: Piezo could be in a leg end cap with eg flat washer above.Its an AC sensor. A strain gauge could do very well.

Answer (score 0):

How about an arduino with an ultrasonic range finder and a bluetooth (or other radio) module?

Place the sensor on the top of the chair back, facing toward the table (but pointed parallel to the ground.)

It will show a high range when no one is there.

When someone sits down, the range will drop.

The arduino reads the range periodically, and reports "seat available" if it has shown high range (or no detection) for some preset number of attempts.

Once you have a working prototype with the arduino, you can simplify the design by using a plain atmel processor of the same type as in your arduino, and combine all the other modules into one unit.

If you go bluetooth, you could use a cheap tablet with bluetooth to display the number of free seats.

If you go with some other radio type, you could use a RaspberryPi with a radio module to drive a display of some kind.

Comment: No doubt a good answer...but ultrasonic sensors may be quite costlier... suppose we have ten tables and each table has two chair type seats on either side then we might need 20 ultrasonic sensors which might lead to more cost.... I might be wrong at this...

Comment: I find ultrasonic modules down to $2.  Against the rest of the stuff, that ought not to be too expensive.

Comment: Oh the last time around 2 years ago I took them it was around 350INR in a local shop.... but 2$... yes is less.....U r right... Also they might sell it for even lesser while selling more units... I live in india and dollars are kinda more for me... :)

Comment: I find dx.com very good for this kind of thing, with free international shipping. http://www.dx.com/p/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-distance-measuring-module-133696 - however, I'm not sure about the power consumption of ultrasonic sensors, it tends to be high, nor about how they interact if you have a lot round a table.